# Border is not being applied to the whole div?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a div (trending-panel) that is only 30% of the total page, in that div contains 10 generated divs (trending-div). The multiple generated divs contain an image, text ($title), and the number of views that article has ($Counter). For some odd reason, when I apply a border to the entire trending-panel, the border does not get applied to the last image and text. Even though the last image and text are printed out, the trending-panel is not counting it for some reason and only prints the border towards the first 9. Here's my code:

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="trending-panel">
                <?php
                    $resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY Counter DESC, dateStamp DESC LIMIT 10");

                    if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
                    {
                        while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $image = $rows["image"];
                            $title = $rows["title"];
                            $link = $rows["link"];
                            $count = $rows["Counter"];

                             echo "<div class='trending-div'><img src='{$image}'/><p>{$title}</p><p id='count'>{$count}</p></div>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div> <!--End of trending panel div-->
```

CSS:

```
.trending-panel{
width: 30%;
border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.trending-div{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.trending-div img{
    width: 45%;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
}

.trending-panel p{
    width: 54%;
    float: right;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
}

#count{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="trending-panel">
                    <div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/bus-falls-in-alligator-pond.jpg'/><p>School Bus Falls Into Alligator Pond</p><p id='count'>202254</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/foods-that-can-kill-you.jpg'/><p>Top Ten Foods That Can Kill You</p><p id='count'>150136</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/most-shocking-facts-about-disney.jpg'/><p>The Top Ten Most Shocking Facts About Disney</p><p id='count'>102508</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/extremely-weird-religions.jpg'/><p>10 Extremely Weird Religions</p><p id='count'>98069</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/entertainment/trump.jpg'/><p>This Is What Would Happen If You Stopped Sleeping</p><p id='count'>45646</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/signs-you-grew-up-in-the-90s.jpg'/><p>10 Signs You Grew Up In The 90s</p><p id='count'>26183</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/no-spin-earth.jpg'/><p>This Is What Would Happen If The Earth Stopped Spinning</p><p id='count'>7144</p></div><div class='trending-div'><img src='/media/thumbnails/bubble-gum-under-shoe.jpg'/><p>10 Unwritten Rules Everyone Should Follow</p><p id='count'>3593</p></div>               </div> <!--End of trending panel div-->
```

Comment: Can you post the generated html?

Comment: @ArleighHix I just did thanks

Comment: The html is invalid, you have more than one `id='count'`, ids should be unique within a page, you should use a class instead. I do not know if this is the cause, but invalid code can often result in unexpected behavior

Comment: Strange, if you add another empty `<div class='trending-div'></div>` after your ten results, they all get borders https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/m2pcL6t3/

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you image tag doesn't have quotes around the src attribute value.  Also add a closer for the image change:

```
    echo "<div class='trending-div'><img src=$image><p>$title</p><p id='count'><$count</p></div>";
```

to:

```
    echo "<div class='trending-div'><img src='{$image}'/><p>{$title}</p><p id='count'>{$count}</p></div>";
```

Try this, you have an '<' before $count, which isn't valid, if you want to use < or > then you have to use escape codes because these mark the start and end of tags.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see all of your code...will try again.

Comment: Hmm, this still isn't working. I removed everything but the title and count too, but it still isn't taking the space of the last article

Comment: What browser are you using, trying using a browser with built in debugging facilities, then check the console and debug windows for errors.